# Can not override Sales Resouce Model Collection class

Tags: magento

I am trying to override **Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection**

My custom module's config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_Salesextend>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Abc_Salesextend>
    </modules>

    <global>       
        <blocks>
            <salesextend>
                <class>Abc_Salesextend_Block</class>   
            </salesextend>  

            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>Abc_Salesextend_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>                
            </adminhtml>    
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <salesextend>
                <class>Abc_Salesextend_Model</class>   
                <resourceModel>salesextend_resource</resourceModel> 
            </salesextend>

            <salesextend_resource>
                <class>Abc_Salesextend_Model_Resource</class>
            </salesextend_resource>

            <!-- HERE is i am trying to override-->

            <sales_resource>
                <rewrite>

                    <order_collection>Abc_Salesextend_Model_Resource_Order_Collection</order_collection>

                </rewrite>                
            </sales_resource>    
        </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

It's not giving me any kind of error even if I place the wrong custom class name. So it's not finding my custom class.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why the rewrite fails. The rewrite definition looks good. The error can only be related to the wrong class used for rewriting, a cache problem (config.xml cache) or to your module not being active.

I guess you want to just manipulate the collection so instead of a rewrite you should use some event/observer technique.

```
/**
 * 
 * Sales order grid collection
 * @param unknown_type $observer
 */
public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer){
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
                $select->DO_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT...
}
```

and this method is triggered by:

```
        <events>
           <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
              <observers>
                  <cartware_modify_grid_adminhtml_collection>
                      <model>your_module/observer_block</model>
                      <method>salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore</method>
                  </cartware_modify_grid_adminhtml_collection>
              </observers>
          </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
<sales>
                <rewrite>

                    <resource_order_collection>Abc_Salesextend_Model_YOURFILENAME</resource_order_collection>

                </rewrite>                
            </sales>
```

just replace with you file name in YOURFILENAME,,,it works...